# Can I use react-native with window manager?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-fragments, android-windowmanager

I know react-native can be used with fragment manager as in https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-android-fragment

How do I use the component in window manager though?

Actually my main aim is to create a "display over other apps"(canDrawOverlays). If I can use any other way other than through window manager that's okay for me too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a react native android app. I want to reuse the component to turn the android app to display over other apps. WindowManager.addView can be used to add a view. But how do i get this view from react native?